# Is there a .Equals function in C# that takes into account nulls?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var upd = newObj.Where(n => oldObj.Any(o =>
  (o.SubTopicId == n.SubTopicId) && 
  (o.Number != n.Number ||
   !o.Name.Equals(n.Name) || 
   !o.Notes.Equals(n.Notes))))
.ToList();
```

What I noticed is that when Notes is null then the .Equals fails.

> .","exceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.","exceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","stackTrace":"
>   at
>   WebRole.Controllers.TopicController.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.b__1(SubTopic
>   o) in C:\H\server\WebRole\Controllers\Web API -
>   Data\TopicController.cs:line 118\r\n   at System

Is there some way that I could the .Equals take into account that either o.Notes or n.Notes could actually be null? Ideally I am wondering if I could have another function as I do this kind of check in quite a few places in my code.

Comment: Why not just use `o.Notes != n.Notes`?  Depending on what `Notes` is it's very likely to give the same result.

Comment: Use `Equals(o.Name, n.Name)`

Comment: @CharlesMager - Will your suggestion of Equals still work if o.Notes or n.Notes is a null ?

Comment: @Marilou yes, see answer below.

Comment: @CharlesMager - Thank you Charles.  I just saw your answer and added a comment to that. Can you check it and let me know if my comment makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the static `object.Equals(object objA, object objB)` method.

Given everything derives from `object`, you can omit the `object` and simply call `Equals`, e.g:

```
 oldObj.Any(o => !Equals(o.Name, n.Name) ...
```

This handles the case where either of the arguments is `null` by returning `false` and returns `true` where both arguments are `null`.

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx):

> - It determines whether the two objects represent the same object reference. If they do, the method returns **true**. This test is equivalent to calling the `ReferenceEquals` method. In addition, if both *objA* and *objB* are **null**, the method returns **true**.
> - It determines whether either *objA* or *objB* is **null**. If so, it returns **false**.
> - If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is **null**, it calls *objA*.**Equals**(*objB*) and returns the result. This means that if *objA* overrides the `Object.Equals(Object)` method, this override is called.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand what are you are saying with Equals but not quite sure about the second code line that starts with oldObj.  If you don't mind could you try to give a longer example that would fit with the code that I have and then I can test that out.  Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @Marilou the `oldObj...` part is literally lifted from your sample code to show that you replace e.g. `!o.Name.Equals(n.Name)` with `!Equals(o.Name, n.Name)`.

Comment: I will try it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the static `object.Equals(object objA, object objB)` method ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx)). This method handles the case where either argument is null before potentially calling `objA.Equals(objB)`.